# How to separate text in same line in text file?

Tags: python, string, text-files

I was trying to read each line in a text files where each line contains id,username,password and append these text(id,username,password) into a list. I tried to separate these text(id,username,password) using
| and use .find("|") to search the starting | and ending | for the text, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

test.txt

```
|ctm1|Jackson|Jacksonmartinez123
|ctm2|Kaijun|Kaijunmartin
```

Python file

```
user = []

with open("test.txt",'r') as userfile: 
     # for each line in test.txt, append id,username and password
     # seperate id,username and password by finding "|"
     for line in userfile.readlines():
          id = line[line.find("|"):line.find("|")]
          username = line[line.find("|"):line.find("|")]
          password = line[line.find("|"):]
          user.append([id.strip("|"),username.strip("|"),password.lstrip("|").rstrip("\n")])
     print(user)
```

Output:

```
[['', '', 'ctm1|Jackson|Jacksonmartinez123'], ['', '', 'ctm2|Kaijun|Kaijunmartin']]
```

Expecting output:

```
[['ctm1', 'Jackson', 'Jacksonmartinez123'], ['ctm2', 'Kaijun', 'Kaijunmartin']]
```

Comment: are you looking for line.split('|')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want split? not strip? here's the core of the solution.

```
string1 = 'ctm1|Jackson|Jacksonmartinez123'
string2 = string1.split('|')
print(string2)
```

Comment: That's really simplify my code a lot, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use `csv` module

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open("test.txt") as userfile:
    reader = csv.reader(userfile, delimiter="|")
    print(list(reader))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
username = line[line.find("|"):line.find("|")]
```

line.find("|") will return the same. So that would be an empty string naturally.

Comment: May I know what's that reason for it to return the same ? Because I thought the way it works is like found | and use : to reach another |. Then the text between | will be there

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work

```
user = []

with open("test.txt","r") as userfile: 
     # for each line in test.txt, append id,username and password
     # separate id,username and password by splitting "|"
     for line in userfile.readlines():
          ID = line.split("|")[1]
          username = line.split("|")[2]
          password = line.split("|")[3].rstrip("\n")
          user.append([ID,username,password])
     print(user)
```

As mentioned by other users I used split instead of find

Comment: No problem. Also, you should avoid using id as a variable name, as id (in lower case) is the name of a built in function.

Comment: oh I didn't aware of that, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution although the other ones look very good also. No extra module needed and works exactly with your example text you supplied.

```
user = []

with open("test.txt",'r') as userfile:
     for line in userfile.readlines():
          user.append(line.strip().split("|")[1:4])
     print(user)
```